# cURL behaves differently with respect to SSL certificates when using -v (verbose) flag?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, curl

Using Ubuntu 16.04, `curl` version 7.47.0

I'm trying to debug an SSL certificate issue, and seeing odd behavior when using `curl`. When I just run:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-81:~$ curl https://myapp.com/hello
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (cloud.mynameserver.com) does not match target host name 'myapp.com'
```

However when I attach the `-v` flag:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-81:~$ curl -v https://myapp.com/hello
*   Trying {IP REDACTED}...
* Connected to myapp.com ({IP REDACTED}) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: myapp.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: CN=myapp.com
*    start date: Sat, 31 Dec 2016 22:57:00 GMT
*    expire date: Fri, 31 Mar 2017 22:57:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=Let's Encrypt,CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: myapp.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2017 00:25:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<
* Connection #0 to host myapp.com left intact
{"message": "Hello World"}
```

Note the very end, `{"message": "Hello World"}`, is the expected response.

Why does `curl` behave differently with respect to its trust of SSL certificate details, when running in verbose mode? This is not specified in the `man` page, so far as I can tell.

Comment: In the verbose mode, it's showing the certificate has `Subject: CN=myapp.com` which means that the cert the server gave that time is for `myapp.com`.   Does `host myapp.com` give more than one IP address? Maybe one of the IPs hosting the site has the wrong cert configured and it's luck of the draw?

Comment: Actually yes, it does give two different IP addresses - one for the nameserver, and one for what I actually expect it to be. The nameserver is a shared VPS with WHM installed, and a number of different accounts (that I administer).

Comment: @DerfK I did indeed have two A records, with different IPs assigned. If you transfer your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as accepted,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have two different `A` (or `AAAA` for IPv6) records with that same hostname.  When there are multiple records for a hostname, this causes each lookup for that hostname to return a different IP address round-robin style.

When you alternate requests with and without verbose mode, the IP address is alternating as well, leading to the non-verbose requests hitting the wrong IP address while the verbose requests hit the correct IP address.  This is why the correct certificate appears in the verbose address according to the

```
subject: CN=myapp.com
```

line, while a different certificate is given in the error for the non-verbose address.

The correct fix for this is to remove the incorrect `A` record so only the addresses of webservers configured to serve your content appear.

Comment: It _was_ really weird. Each time I ran `host myapp.com`, I would get the same two IP addresses, but in a different order. It was consistently flip-flopping.

Comment: Yes, clients should use the first IP in the list to connect to.  This is normally used for very basic load-balancing since every request would go to a different server